# Were or was, the majority of people concerned?

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-they

I have checked the possible duplicates which flagged up on this and I have attempted research with no conclusion. ELU is my final port of call.

I wrote, on another forum of Stack Exchange :

> 'the majority of people was concerned about . . .'

And I have just altered it to :

> 'the majority of people were concerned . . '

and I am now in a state of conflict so great that I cannot eat my breakfast.

Can you help ?